# java.io.FileNotFoundException when running JUnit tests through Gradle on command line

Tags: gradle, junit, cygwin

I'm using Gradle 2.7 on Windows 7.  When I run my JUnit tests, most of which are structured like so:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations= {"classpath:/META-INF/spring/cbmyproject-testing-context.xml", "classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-myproject-mvc.xml"})
public class MyprojectApplicationServiceTest {
```

And then I run the command

```
gradle build
```

The tests die with errors like below ...

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [META-INF/spring/cbmyproject-testing-context.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [META-INF/spring/cbmyproject-testing-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:253)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:122)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
```

These tests run fine when I run them through Eclipse.  What do I need to adjust in Gradle so that these tests run normally when I run them through a command line?